# Data Discrepancy Between Shopify Online Store Revenue And Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, shopify, credit-card, google-analytics-4

I am seeing a discrepancy in my shopify store and google analytics ecommerce revenue tracking. After few hours attempts in testing, I realized that only when I choose credit card as payment method, this occurs. In settings -> checkout I have a script to redirect it to payment gateway as attached below.

[image: Shopify Additional Script Screenshot]

Once it is done, user will be directed to payment gateway and payment will be done. After payments -> shopify's online store has the sales record and revenue is added when in Google Analytics no changes at all. Am I missing configurations? Should I also include post purchase additional scripts?

Comment: What other type  of payments you have?

Comment: Cash on delivery and Card on delivery @FabioFilippi